# A website is stopping access from Tor, are there any solutions?

Tags: anonymity, censorship, ip-address

Here's the issue with a website.

When I used VPN plus Tor: I got banned.

When I use VPN (but use a normal browser), I am Ok and can normally do what I have to do at that website.

So, if the Tor exit nodes are publicly known, and the websites have software to sniff our Tor, then the number of websites that disallow Tor will increasingly grow. and there will be a day when Tor can't be used on any website at all, if my logic is OK so far.

So can anyone shed any more light on this? How do I use Tor and not get banned at a website?

I don't have to use any bridge software as I can access Tor directly.

Comment: *In short:* The problem here lurks at the website's purpose and the kind of data it's processing: if you'll add more details like the address of a website and/or what you're unable to do - the answer will be more precise. *In long words:* Some kind of actions can be only done when the personification of the user is not just clear, but flawless, for example: online banking, petition signing, electronical government services for citizens and many others. Not because the site owners are badasses or something similar - the *site purpose itself* or *a kind of information/action provided* may requir

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is not okay so far.

Here are some links you might find useful:

[A call to arms: Helping Internet services accept anonymous users](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/call-arms-helping-internet-services-accept-anonymous-users)

[The Trouble with CloudFlare](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/trouble-cloudflare)

Ultimately there is no technical solution to the problem that does not compromise your anonymity. Exit points being known protects the people who operate them (e.g. [Exonerator](https://exonerator.torproject.org/)).

The correct solution to this problem is advocacy, as per the first link above! You should contact the sites owners and encourage them to either allow anonymous access or find better means of stopping abuses of the service they provide, rather than a blanket blacklist.

Comment: From your answer, 'activism' takes a pretty long time to work, if it works at all. Activism in the world where 'transparency' is the gospel of all World governments that are trying to control people? Activism in the face of websites like Wiki denying Tor? Wouldn't hold my breath. And from the lack of counter logic on your part, my logic does seem Ok so far. The only useful info I find from your post is that there is no technical solution to this problem. Yeah: figured as much. :-(

Comment: Your "logic" is a specific type of logical fallacy called the [Slippery Slope Fallacy](http://www.logicalfallacies.info/presumption/slippery-slope/).