# How do i avoid the "i am not a robot" verification when i open a new website?

Tags: configuration, browsers, cloudflare

I am new to Tor, as soon as i installed and started surfing. The browser started asking me to verify if i was a robot for every new website i access. 
How can i avoid it?

Comment: It's likely that the sites you're trying to navigate to are behind a Cloudflare firewall. Short of contacting the site and telling them that Cloudflare is preventing you from using the site while using Tor, there's probably not much you can do. This official blog post might be of interest: https://blog.torproject.org/blog/trouble-cloudflare

Comment: on some sites, while behind a specific proxy, you will be directed to the robots check page no matter what. on other sites the robot check could be bypassed by enabling java script. but then you could be tracked. in tor browser you could allow scrips globally in the noscript add-on. but this is probably not advised because then you could be tracked. i think it's a small prize to pay to stay anonymous. but you could try enabling javascript if it's a site you feel "is safe" ;) this is my experience on how to get around the robots check.

Answer (score 1):

See: https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/10456/12737 *(can't mark as duplicate, no votes or accepted answers. seems a problem with stackexchange and anonymity where people ask with "anonymous" accounts which are discarded. no one comes back to accept the answer once it's answered...)*